# Webpack 5 IgnorePlugin - Not ignoring JS file from output on CSS files only?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to use the Webpack's IngorePlugin. I am using my Webpack file only to create a CSS file. On build, it outputs a JS file. But I don't want that. Tried ignoring JS files but still outputs it.

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/js\/(?!admin)/),
```

Outputs in the ROOT folder. So I want to disable all JS files from the output in the root folder. "admin" is the file being created.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To properly answer your question, it'd be helpful if you posted a link to the full WP config file and an example of the file that's being processed.

Also, you mentioned you're only using WP to create a CSS file, does that mean you're just trying to use something like SASS, Stylus, Less, etc? If so, you could probably just set up a `package.json` script to compile your CSS without WP.
For example, if you have a `.scss` file, you could install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), and create a simple Node script to compile what file you pass in as an arg.

```sh
bin/
  - build-css.js
src/
  - styles.sass
```

Within `build-css.js`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { basename, resolve } = require('path');
const sass = require('node-sass');

const [...files] = process.argv.slice(2);

if (files.length) {
  files.forEach((relativeFilePath) => {
    const fileName = basename(relativeFilePath, '.scss');
    
    sass.render(
      {
        file: resolve(__dirname, relativeFilePath),
        outFile: resolve(__dirname, `./public/css/${fileName}.css`),
      },
      (err, result) => { console.log(err); }
    );
  });
}
else {
  console.log('No files were provided to process');
}
```

Within `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "node ./bin/build-css.js"
}
```

The above has the benefit of giving you the control of how your files are processed at a more granular level, and you're only locked in to any SCSS changes, instead of Webpack and SCSS.

If you're using WP for it's file watching capabilities, you could instead wire up [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) to run the new script when you change files.